# C Array of Counters

Tags: c, arrays, equation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int i;      //Counting Variable for loop
    int sales[30];      //Array for sales people

    //Creates Gross for 30 Indiviudals
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        sales[i] = ( rand() % 15000) + 1;
    }
    printf("Original List\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", sales[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Im tying to make a program that takes 30 random numbers between 0 and 15000, then applies the equation (100+a*0.09), then sorts the answers from highest to lowest. Im getting stuck on how to apply the equation to the values founded in the array since they are program generated.

Comment: You mean between 1 and 15000?

Comment: `printf("%f\n", 100 + sales[i] * 0.09);`?

Comment: That just gives me a single value, I need it so that every number that was randomly selected in the array gets that equation applied to it and lists it

Comment: The `[i]` in `printf("%f\n", 100 + sales[i] * 0.09);` hints that that is done in a loop and so provides more than one sum.

Answer (score 1):

you can just loop through the array again and assign them again just like you looped through the two previous times

```
for (i=0; i < 30; i++){
    sales[i] = 100 + sales[i] * .09;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean:

```
for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    printf("%f\n", 100 + (float)sales[i] * 0.09);
}
```

?

You can also store it in an other array (of float/double). Not sure to understand correctly as it seems very simple!

Edit: if you need to sort it you would have to store it in an array (float vals[30]; let say) and then have a look to 'qsort(…)' function in order to order the values.

Comment: Thank You that helps alot, I'm really new to c programming, or even programming in general